# try ,catch, finally execution

Tags: java, try-catch, try-finally

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [throws Exception in finally blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481446/throws-exception-in-finally-blocks)

- The catch block is only executed if an exception is thrown in the try block.
- The finally block is executed always after the try(-catch) block, if an exception is thrown or not.

My question is **IF** I got Exception in finally block than how to handle it ?????

Comment: catch it and handle or throw it? Depends completely on your application.

Comment: Maybe inner try block in outer finally block?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481446/throws-exception-in-finally-blocks

Comment: You can throw an exception which results in a value returned (in either a catch or finally block) and you can return a value which results in an exception (from a finally block)

Answer (score 7):

This is a well-known problem/gotcha in the Java language specification, in the sense that if an exception is thrown within the finally clause (without handling it in a nested try-catch) , the original exception gets lost. You will need to nest a new try-catch to catch the new exception, and process it there.

Comment: in java 7 there is a way to handle it.  there is now a notion of "suppressed" exceptions where you can tie multiple exceptions together (see [Throwable.addSuppressed()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed%28java.lang.Throwable%29)).  this was added for the new try-with-resources feature.

Comment: +1 You have the same problem with throwing exceptions in the catch block.

Answer (score 3):

You have to handle **Exception in finally block**

like

```
finally{
    try
    {
       ///
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      ///  
    }
}
```