# How to close IOs?

Tags: java, io

when i managed IO, i found a problem. i used to close it like this:

```
try {
        // my code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // my code
    } finally{
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

but the close method also would throw exception. if i have more than one IO, i have to close all of them. so the code maybe like this:

```
try {
    // my code
} catch (Exception e) {
    // my code
} finally{
    if (is1 != null) {
        is1.close();
    }
    if(is2 != null{
        is2.close();
    }
    // many IOs
}
```

if is1.close() throws an exception, is2, is3 would not close itself. So i have to type many try-catch-finally to control them. is there other way to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [throws Exception in finally blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481446/throws-exception-in-finally-blocks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, you could use a `closeQuietly(...)` method from Apache [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html).  These methods squash any `IOException` emanating from the `close()`, and also take care of the case where the argument is `null`.

The only thing you should watch is that you don't call it on a output stream that has unflushed data.  If you do and the flush fails, you won't hear about it.  If the data you are writing is important, not knowing that flush failed would be A BAD THING.

Answer (score 1):

I use this little static utility class, on the principle that if you really must do something (anything) verbose in error your handling or finally blocks, then atleast rip-it-out and implement the damn thing once, instead of littering your application code with distractions from the task at hand:

```
package krc.utilz.io;

import java.io.Closeable;
import krc.utilz.reflectionz.Invoker;

public abstract class Clozer
{
  /**
   * close these "streams"
   * @param Closeable... "streams" to close.
   */
  public static void close(Closeable... streams) {
    Exception x = null;
    for(Closeable stream : streams) {
      if(stream==null) continue;
      try {
        stream.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        if(x!=null)x.printStackTrace();
        x = e;
      }
    }
    if(x!=null) throw new RuntimeIOException(x.getMessage(), x);
  }

  /**
   * Close all the given objects, regardless of any errors.
   * <ul>
   * <li>If a given object exposes a close method then it will be called. 
   * <li>If a given object does NOT expose a close method then a warning is 
   *   printed to stderr, and that object is otherwise ignored.
   * <li>If any invocation of object.close() throws an IOException then
   *     <ul>
   *     <li>we immediately printStackTrace
   *     <li>we continue to close all given objects
   *     <li>then at the end we throw an unchecked RuntimeIOException
   *     </ul>
   * </ul>
   * @param Object... objects to close.
   */
  public static void close(Object... objects) {
    Exception x = null;
    for(Object object : objects) {
      if(object==null) continue;
      try {
        Invoker.invoke(object, "close", new Object[]{} );
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException eaten) {
        // do nothing
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        x = e;
      }
    }
    if(x!=null) throw new RuntimeIOException(x.getMessage(), x);
  }

}
```

Note that the LAST close-exception, if any, is still thrown, unlike the common `try{stream1.close();}catch{} try{stream2.close();}catch{}` cop-out.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: `for(Closeable stream : streams)` ---- Streams is an array of IOs? if yes! How to declare an array of IOs?